# Find file including full path in name search

Tags: android, linux, find

I was using "`find / -name xxx`" but it searches only for the file name.

What I want is to include results containing "`xxx`" in the full path to the file.
For instance I want a file with path "`/data/xxx/somefile.txt`" to be included in the results.

How can I achieve this on an Android device?

Comment: @Fivesheep thanks it works, though its much slower.

Comment: @Fivesheep You should put this as an answer so that gosho_ot_pochivka can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fivesheep's comment worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -wholename "*xxx*"
```

or in case you need only dirs with such name

```
find . -wholename "*/xxx/*"
```

Comment: It seems that -wholename is not supported on android when I use it it prints "find: unrecognized: -wholename" and after that the manual of the find command.

Comment: Seems it is present only in GNU version. Try @Fivesheep's variant with `-regex`.